# How do I access an attached thumb drive?

Tags: cyanogenmod, file-management, usb-on-the-go, oneplus-one

I've attached an external drive to my phone using a USB-OTG cable. I can open it in File Manager (v2.0.0), but when I go to /storage/usbdisk none of my files show up, and if I try to create a file it complains about needing elevated permissions. I've read online that I need to enable root access mode in File Manager's general settings, but there is no such setting on my device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out you have to enable "Superuser" mode in CM's settings app if it's disabled. I was only able to get to this setting by searching for it - I couldn't find it anywhere in the menu tree. Android normally restricts apps to only access their own special sub-folders on an attached flash drive, so File Manager needs special permissions to access everything.

Answer (score 0):

I own a OnePlus One and, after plugging the USB Drive through OTG cable, use the [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) app which will save you from the hassle of permissions. In that app look under the Local tab to find your drive, usually called sdb. No need for root.